# How to create a linked assets folder in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

In eclipse I had my assets folder as a linked directory. Is there a way to do this in Android Studio?

Comment: ... what changes, in AS?

Comment: but not at the `assets` folder level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, you do it in gradle

```
assets.srcDirs = ['path']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are following step to add asset folder in android studio

```
1. Right click on app folder
2. Select New menu from list
3. Select Folder menu from list
4. Select Assets Folder menu from list
5. At last click on Finish button
```